# How to build an empty generic IMongoQueryable<TEntity> type queryable object

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

The method I use is returning a queryable object of type `IMongoQueryable<TEntity>`. Result of this method returns `default(IMongoQueryable<TEntity>)` when mongodb database throws an error. Instead of the default result, I want to replace that row with an empty queryable object, however MongoDb Linq library does not provide any.

```
//Sample of the code
public IMongoQueryable<TEntity> AllQueryable<TEntity>(AggregateOptions options = null) where TEntity : Entity
{
    try
    {
        return GetCollection<TEntity>().AsQueryable(options);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return default(IMongoQueryable<TEntity>);
    }
}
```

So, how can I implement a custom type equivalent to the `Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>().AsQueryable()` or something like `IEnumerable<TEntity>().AsMongoQueryable()`?

```
//I need something like this
public IMongoQueryable<TEntity> AllQueryable<TEntity>(AggregateOptions options = null) where TEntity : Entity
{
    try
    {
        return GetCollection<TEntity>().AsQueryable(options);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>().AsMongoQueryable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you debug your C# application you can notice that running `.AsQueryable<T>` on MongoDB collection returns an instance of [MongoQueryableImpl](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/MongoQueryableImpl.cs) class which is **internal** in `MongoDB.Driver.Linq` namespace. You can try to instantiate that class using reflection but there's an easier way.

You can implement your own implementation of `IMongoQueryable<T>` interface following the Null Object design pattern.

The interface requires a handful of methods but you can keep most of them unimplemented - you'll never need them. So your `EmptyMongoQueryable<T>` may look like this:

```
public class EmptyMongoQueryable<T> : IMongoQueryable<T>
{
    public Expression Expression => Expression.Constant(this, typeof(IMongoQueryable<T>));
    public Type ElementType => typeof(T);
    public IQueryProvider Provider => new EmptyQueryProvider();
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield break;
    }

    public QueryableExecutionModel GetExecutionModel() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IAsyncCursor<T> ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public Task<IAsyncCursor<T>> ToCursorAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Then you can run following code:

```
var queryable = new EmptyMongoQueryable<YourType>();
var emptyList = queryable.ToList();
```

EDIT: since you've mentioned in a comment that you want to run `.Where()` you need to provide the `IQueryProvider`. Same story - MongoDB driver uses internal class but you can create your own:

```
public class EmptyQueryProvider : IQueryProvider
{
    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression) => null;
    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression) => new EmptyMongoQueryable<TElement>();
    public object Execute(Expression expression) => default(object);
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression) => default(TResult);
}
```

This will allow you to run `Where()` on your `EmptyMongoQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for great answer @mickl but it throws an error when I filter on `a => !a.MyBooleanValue` predicate.
Ex; `var myQueryable = _myRepository.AllQueryable().Where(a => !a.MyBooleanValue)`
Probably, I should implement `IQueryProvider`  interface and set the _Provider_ property in `EmptyMongoQueryable` class.

Comment: @tsubasaetkisi yes, this complicates things but I've added simple `IQueryProvider` and `.Where()` works. Try my updated answer